# javascript with XMLHttpRequest not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have tried everything suggested in questions of similar nature but this very basic code is just not working. I just want to receive the message from the php code in the same file using `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="qwer" style="height:50px;width:40px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function check() {
    var ualias=document.getElementById('ualias').value;
    var resu=document.getElementById("qwer");
    var params="username="+ualias;
    var hm = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://'my-domain-name'/try.php";
    hm.open("GET", url+"?"+params, true);
    hm.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(hm.readyState == 4 && hm.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hm.responseText;
            resu.innerHTML=return_data;
        } else {
            resu.innerHTML="error";
        }
        hm.send(null); 
        resu.innerHTML="CHECKING...";
    }
}
</script>
<?php if(isset($_GET['username'])) {
    $u=$_GET['username'];
    echo $u;
    exit();
} ?>
<input id='ualias' type='text' onblur=''>
<button type='button' onclick="check()">Go!</button>
</body>  
</html>
```

The browser (Google Chrome) isn't showing anything for the `onclick` event.

It finally worked. I made the following edits.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
   <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function check()
    {
      var ualias=document.getElementById('ualias').value;
  var resu=document.getElementById("qwer");
  var params="username="+ualias;
  var hm = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var url = "http://www.websamaj.in/try.php";
      hm.open("GET", url+"?"+params, true);
      hm.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(hm.readyState == 4 && hm.status == 200) 
     {
         var return_data = hm.responseText;
         resu.innerHTML=return_data;

     }
     }
  hm.send(null);
      resu.innerHTML="wait...";   
     }
     </script>
 <?php
 if(isset($_GET['username']))
 {
    $u=$_GET['username'];
    echo $u.",you are finally here!:)";
    exit();
}
?>
    <input id='ualias' type='text' onblur=''>
 <button type='button' onclick="check()">Go!</button>
<div id="qwer" style="height:50px;width:100px;background-color:#CCC;"></div> 

     </body>     
     </html>
```

Apparently, the else condition there in onreadystatechange function was causing a problem. I would love it if anybody could tell me why exactly was that creating a problem. As far as i know, onreadystatechange event is called each time the state changes. So in my previous code, "error" should be overwritten thrice on the div and then, when the state changes to 4 and 200, the responseText should be overwritten, since i didnt use append. So, an explanation would be highly acknowledged. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure this is a js issue and not a php issue?

Comment: Is there any error in debug console? Can you check request is getting send in network console

Comment: This is not needed in your PHP: exit();

Comment: In this case `exit` is needed to stop the PHP script from doing anything else.

Comment: i have checked the php by manually adding the the username variable to the url. That is working. So, i guess the problem is with js.

Comment: @RaunakKathuria, the request is being sent. I saw in the network console. its giving status 200(OK)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original code, `hm.send(null)` and `resu.innerHTML="CHECKING"` lines are actually INSIDE the onreadystatechange callback:

```
hm.open("GET", url+"?"+params, true);
hm.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(hm.readyState == 4 && hm.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hm.responseText;
        resu.innerHTML=return_data;
    } else {
        resu.innerHTML="error";
    }
    hm.send(null); // <-- wrong place!
    resu.innerHTML="CHECKING...";
}
```

In your edited version, you moved them out of there (fixed indention):

```
 hm.open("GET", url+"?"+params, true);
 hm.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if(hm.readyState == 4 && hm.status == 200) {
         var return_data = hm.responseText;
         resu.innerHTML=return_data;
     } else {
         resu.innerHTML="error";
     }
 }
 hm.send(null);
 resu.innerHTML="wait...";
```

The reason you didn't notice this is because in your edited version, you didn't indent your blocks correctly. Recommend always keeping your code formatted consistently, even when hacking around, so you can see the code blocks.